# Angular2 jasmine test fails with inline template:0:0 caused by: null is not an object

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a basic directive which acts on an input box to limit the lowest value allowed, in this test case nothing less than zero.

However, I can't get this test to pass because of the error inline template:0:0 caused by: null is not an object .

It seems to maybe be related to ngModel but none of my searches on the interwebs of the YouBooks or FaceTubes or Yahoogles yields an answer.

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
selector: '[dleGbMinValue]',
providers: [NgModel]
})

export class MinValueDirective {

@Input('dleGbMinValue') minValue : string;

constructor(private el: ElementRef, private model: NgModel) { }

@HostListener('change') onChange() {
if (this.el.nativeElement.value && parseFloat(this.el.nativeElement.value) < parseFloat(this.minValue)) {
  this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(parseFloat(this.minValue));
  this.model.viewToModelUpdate(parseFloat(this.minValue));
  }
}

@HostListener('blur') onBlur() {
if (!this.el.nativeElement.value || parseFloat(this.el.nativeElement.value) < parseFloat(this.minValue)) {
  this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(parseFloat(this.minValue));
  this.model.viewToModelUpdate(parseFloat(this.minValue));
   }
  }
}
```

And here it the test code

```js
import { MinValueDirective } from './min-value.directive';

@Component({
  template: `<input type="number" dleGbMinValue="0">`
})

class TestMinValueDirectiveComponent {
}

describe('Directive: MinValueDirective', () => {

  let component: TestMinValueDirectiveComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestMinValueDirectiveComponent>;
  let inputEl: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestMinValueDirectiveComponent, MinValueDirective]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestMinValueDirectiveComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should stop at min value on change', () => {

    expect(inputEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual('');
    inputEl.nativeElement.value = '-5';
    inputEl.triggerEventHandler('change', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual(0);
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi there. Edits to remove thanks and other niceties are considered acceptable on this platform. Here is [the canonical reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to provide `NgModel` in `MinValueDirective`.

Use `ngModel` directive from `FormsModule` instead.

```
@Component({ 
  template: `<input type="number" ngModel dleGbMinValue="0">` // add ngModel
})
class TestMinValueDirectiveComponent {}
```

Don't forget to import `FormsModule` to your testing module:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [FormsModule], // here
  declarations: [TestMinValueDirectiveComponent, MinValueDirective]
});
```

Then to prevent error: `inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'target' of null` from `NumberValueAccessor` change

```
inputEl.triggerEventHandler('change', null);
```

to

```
inputEl.triggerEventHandler('change', { target: { value: '-5'}});
```

A complete test you can find in **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/AfmN1ecqA0YRDZxBTDXB?p=preview)**